# Cannot set property 'editable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties, undefined

I'm trying to change the value of the property of an object that is part of an array of objects and get the following message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'editable' of undefined
```

Printing the value of this property to the console works, but changing it does not. Following is my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/UtpFU/5/

How do I change the value of an object that is part of an array of objects in the above jsfiddle?

```
//data file
var data = [
    {editable:true,greeting:'hello'},
    {editable:true,greeting:'bye'},
    {editable:true,greeting:'good morning'}
];

//updating data
var readWrite = function (text, label, value){
    for (i=0;i<=text.length;i++){
        if (label=='editable'){
            if (value==true){
                //changing the value of the editable property DOES NOT WORK
                text[i].editable=true;
            }
                else {
                    text[i].editable=false;
                }
        }
    }
    //printing data after changing the values of its properties
    console.log(data);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //printing data to the console
    console.log(data);
    //updating data and printing it to the console - DOES NOT WORK - what am I missing?
    readWrite(data, 'editable', true);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop isn't right, change to `<=` to `<`:

```
for (i=0;i<text.length;i++){
```

Using `<=` is going out of bounds making `text[i]` undefined. It iterates all objects, then tries to iterate one more, which doesn't exist.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtpFU/6/).